# Finding the next value of an array

Tags: php

Here I need to check whether the value comes after `1` is `1.1.` Next value comes after `1.1` is `1.2.` etc.

The next value after a given value is takes by  `$C=$A[i]+'.'+$count;` but when I print it prints values `1,2,3,4` etc. Is the way I have approached to the problem incorrect.

```
<?
$A=array(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4);

$count=0;

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($A);$i++){
$count++;
$B=$A[$count];
$C=$A[i]+'.'+$count;

if($B==$C){
//a code goes here

}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
<?php
$a=array(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4);
$count=0;

foreach($a as $v)
{
    $c = "1".'.'.$count;
    if($c==$v)
    {
       echo "Match Found";
    }
    $count++;

}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying and explaining. could you please explain $c = "1".'.'.$count; this please.

Comment: `$c` holds the variable 1.1 , 1.2 , 1.3 etc.. `.` is the operator used for concatenation.

Comment: But what the problem I face is I do not need to take 1 as a string. Instead I want to take the array value based on its index. As $a[i] in your case. If so based on my example how can I do the concatenation? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Hope this will be correct. $C=$A[i].'.'.$count; Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You had a lot of syntax error, every variable in php must be prefixed with $. You missed that on the i-variable a couple of times. You also missed brackets in the for-loop. And your $A variable was printed out because it was written before the PHP-tag.

I cleaned it up and corrected those issues:

```
$A = array(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4);
$count = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($A) - 1; $i++){
    $count++;
    $B = $A[$count];
    $C = $A[$i] + 0.1;

    if($B == $C){
        // This will be executed every time the next value is "current + 0.1".
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying and explaining. But $C = $A[$i] + 0.1; is not actually what I wanted. later through another for loop I should check whether 1.1.1 , 1.1.2 etc. is too there. So I should make simply a string if I'm correct. How can I adjust it?